# Wirtinger inequality with nule integral

Tags: real-analysis

If $f \in {\mathcal{C}}^1([- \pi , \pi])$, with $f(- \pi) = f(\pi)$, such that $\int_{- \pi}^{\pi} f(t) \, dt = 0$, how can I prove that
$$
\int_{- \pi}^{\pi} {|f(t)|}^2 \, dt \leq \int_{- \pi}^{\pi} {|f'(t)|}^2 \, dt\mbox{?}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a_0,a_1,a_2,....$ and $b_1, b_2, b_3,....$ the Fourier coefficients of $f$. From $\int_{- \pi}^{\pi} f(t) \, dt = 0$ we get $a_0=0$ and then, by Parseval's identity:

$\int_{- \pi}^{\pi} {|f(t)|}^2 dt=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty}(a_n^2+b_n^2)$

and

$\int_{- \pi}^{\pi} {|f'(t)|}^2 dt=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty}n^2(a_n^2+b_n^2)$.

Comment: Thank you by the observation that $a_0 = 0$, but how can you deduce the Wirtinger inequaliry now?

Comment: $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty}(a_n^2+b_n^2) \le \sum _{n=1}^{\infty}n^2(a_n^2+b_n^2)$

Comment: And how can I prove these inequality?

Comment: This inequality is trivial because $n^2\geq 1$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $a_n^2+b_n^2$ is positive

Comment: But if $f(\mathbb{R}) \subset \mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R}$, can I obtain the same with ${|a_n|}^2 + {|b_n|}^2$ instead of ${a_n}^2 + {b_n}^2$?

Comment: I think this should be the real resp. the imaginary part of the coefficient ($c_n=a_n+b_ni \Rightarrow |c_n|^2=a_n^2+b_n^2$) and thus they are always real.

Comment: Ok I understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is a more or less direct consequence of Parseval's identity: We have $$f(x)=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\hat{f}(k)e^{ikx}$$
with the fourier coefficients defined as $\hat{f}(\xi):=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)e^{-ix\xi}dx$
and
$$f'(x)=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\widehat{f'} (k)e^{ikx}.$$
Let's calculate the coefficients $\widehat{f'} (k)$:
For $\xi=0$ we get $\widehat{f'}(0) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f'(x)dx=0$ by the presumption. Note that presumption gives us $\widehat{f}(0)=0$, too. Thus we will omit the summand for $k=0$ in the series later. Now for $\xi\neq 0$ with partial integration we obtain
\begin{align}
\widehat{f'}(\xi) &= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f'(x)e^{-ix\xi}dx
= \frac{1}{2\pi}\left(\underbrace{f(x)e^{-ix\xi}|_{-\pi}^\pi}_{0} + i\xi\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)e^{-ix\xi}dx\right)\\
&= i\xi\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)e^{-ix\xi}dx = i\xi\hat{f}(\xi).
\end{align}
With this calculation and Parseval's identity follows
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2\pi}&\int_{-\pi}^\pi |f'(x)|^2dx =: \|f'\|_2^2 = \sum_{k\neq 0}|\widehat{f'} (k)|^2\\
&= \sum_{k\neq 0}k^2|\hat{f} (k)|^2
\geq \sum_{k\neq 0}|\hat{f} (k)|^2 \\
&= \|f\|_2^2 := \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi |f(x)|^2dx.
\end{align}
Multiplying with $2\pi$ gives the statement.